# write regexp to read sentence from text file in matlab

Tags: regex, matlab, nlp

```
<s> an evolutionary immune network for data clustering </s>
<s> an evolutionary immune network for data clustering </s>
<s> inet an extensible framework for simulating immune network </s>
<s> immunity based systems a survey </s>
<s> a recommender system based on the immune network </s>
```

I am working in MATLAB and these sentences are from the text file, I want to read these sentences line by line and want to extract each word as well as count the frequency of each word. How can I use the "regexp" function to extract the words?

Comment: Have you looked up the documentation for [regexp](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html)?

Comment: @Doresoom yes i read that, and to read text file i wrote the following code   F = fread(fid','*char')'; 
unigram = sort(unique(regexp(F , ' ', 'split')));and in this procedure it showing "<s></s>" as a one word but these are different and i want to separate them

Answer (score 0):

The reason `</s><s>` is considered one word is that you've read the entire file and are only splitting on spaces, not newlines and spaces.

Instead, read the file line-by-line with `fgets` and split the lines individually, incrementing the token counts as you go.

Answer (score 0):

I think the string `'<s></s>'` occurs literally somewhere in your text file. If that is the case, splitting on spaces is of course insufficient; you'd have to return all the occurrences of `'<s>'`, `'</s>'` or consecutive non-space characters:

```
regexp(F, '<s>|\w*|</s>', 'match');
```

Complete code:

```
% Read file contents
fid = fopen('test.txt','r');
F = fread(fid, '*char').';
fclose(fid);

% Split all words
C = regexp(F, '<s>|\w*|</s>', 'match');

% Find word frequencies
words  = unique(C);
counts = cellfun(@(x)sum(strcmp(x,C)), words);

% Group them together for display
freq = [num2cell(counts.') words.']
```

Comment: thx @Rody Oldenhuis this one is working for me, can you give me a little bit description about the regexp which one you gave?

Comment: This regexp is also splitting each  word  **regexp(F, ' |\n', 'split')**

Comment: I understand the regular exp, now how can i calculate the **frequency** of each word.

Comment: @user2753079: See my latest edit. For future reference, you really asked two separate questions here (how to `regexp`, and how to count word frequency); so in the future, please post two questions.

Comment: Thx @Rody Oldenhuis for your answer also for suggestion.